# Swift Unable to Append String to an Array looked up with a dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift

Any idea why this code is not working?

```
var apples = [String]()
var oranges = [String]()
var bananas = [String]()

var optionArrays : [String : [String]] = [
    "apple" : apples,
    "orange" : oranges,
    "banana" : bananas
]

optionArrays["apple"]!.append("Macintosh")
optionArrays["apple"]!.count // 1

apples.count // 0 -> Why isn't there already one apple?
apples.append("Golden Delicious")
apples.count // 1
```

For some reason the `optionArrays["apple"]` seems to be working, but no the actual apples array.  Shouldn't this work?

Comment: You never assigned something to the `apples` array. You did it for the `optionsArrays`.

Comment: @GuyDaher is there anyway to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Basically I want to populate a variable array, if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are value types in swift. When you put them into dictionaries:

```
var optionArrays : [String : [String]] = [
    "apple" : apples,
    "orange" : oranges,
    "banana" : bananas
]
```

Copies of the actual `apples`, `oranges` and `bananas` arrays are created and put into the dictionary. When you modify the dictionary:

```
optionArrays["apple"]!.append("Macintosh")
```

you only modify the *copy* of `apples` that is in the dictionary.

A workaround is to assign all the copies of the arrays to the actual arrays whenever the dictionary is modfied:

```
var optionArrays : [String : [String]] = [
    "apple" : apples,
    "orange" : oranges,
    "banana" : bananas
    ] {
didSet {
    apples = optionArrays["apple"]!
    oranges = optionArrays["orange"]!
    bananas = optionArrays["banana"]!
}
}
```

Another workaround is to create a reference type wrapper for `Array`:

```
class RefArray<T> { // you can consider conforming to ExpressibleByArrayLiteral
    var innerArray = [T]()
}

var apples = RefArray<String>()
var oranges = RefArray<String>()
var bananas = RefArray<String>()

var optionArrays : [String : RefArray<String>] = [
    "apple" : apples,
    "orange" : oranges,
    "banana" : bananas
    ]

optionArrays["apple"]!.innerArray.append("Macintosh")
optionArrays["apple"]!.innerArray.count // 1

apples.innerArray.count
```

Comment: thank you, your first work around worked great!  Using the didSet event is exactly what I needed!  Thank you so much, I've been scratching my head all day on this!

Answer (score 0):

#### It like that because Swift array is value type not reference type

```
var apples = [String]()
var oranges = [String]()
var bananas = [String]()

var optionArrays : [String : [String]] = [
    "apple" : apples,
    "orange" : oranges,
    "banana" : bananas
]

print("Initial values")
print(apples)
```

> []

```
print(optionArrays)
```

> ["apple": [], "orange": [], "banana": []]

```
optionArrays["apple"]!.append("Macintosh")
optionArrays["apple"]!.count // 1

print("Values after update optionArrays")
print(apples)
```

> []

```
print(optionArrays)
```

> ["apple": ["Macintosh"], "orange": [], "banana": []]

You will see here that `apples array` is not updated just an `optionArrays` is updated. Because swift's array is not reference typr it is value typr so `apples` will copied to an optionArrays array, so optionArrays will update separately. and also apples will update separately.

So apples.count will be 0

Now try update `apple array` values
apples.append("Golden Delicious")
apples.count // 1

But now optionArrays value remain same as before

```
print(optionArrays)
```

> ["apple": ["Macintosh"], "orange": [], "banana": []]
>       optionArrays["apple"]

```
print(apples)
```

> ["Golden Delicious"]